# "pkg-config script could not be found" on OSX

Tags: linux, macos

I am trying to install some software on my mac; however I keep receiving the same error:

```
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XMEDCON_GLIB_CFLAGS
and XMEDCON_GLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

To get pkg-config, see <http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/>.
See `config.log' for more details
```

I am not quite sure how to go about adding the pkg-config to the PATH. I have seen online (see link) that I should add the following:

[Link showing how to direct PATH variable](http://www.fantageek.com/318/install-pkg-config-for-mac-osx/)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin     # Fixed typo as mentioned in comment
```

which is where I have placed pkg-config. I still keep getting the error though every time I try to configure the files using ./configure. Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a colon in `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin`. This presumes that `/opt/local/bin/pkg-config` exists and is the version you want.

Comment: My apologies for the typo. The problem is after typing this into the terminal followed by the ./configure command, I still receive this error. Any ideas as to what may be the problem?

Comment: What is the output from `which pkg-config`?

Comment: '/opt/local/bin/pkgconfig/bin/pkg-config' is what I get back where my PATH is set to /opt/local/bin/pkgconfig/bin

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Answer to my question (after several Google searches) revealed the following:

```
$ curl https://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.29.tar.gz -o pkgconfig.tgz
$ tar -zxf pkgconfig.tgz && cd pkg-config-0.29
$ ./configure && make install
```

from the following link: [Link showing above](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX)

Thanks to everyone for their comments, and sorry for my linux/OSX ignorance!

Doing this fixed my issues as mentioned above.

Comment: Running these commands on Ubuntu 12.04 gives the error: `configure: error: Either a previously installed pkg-config or "glib-2.0 >= 2.16" could not be found. Please set GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS to the correct values or pass --with-internal-glib to configure to use the bundled copy.`

Comment: for ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt-get install pkg-config`

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS, if you want 0.29 instead of the default 0.26 (which is too old to cross-compile ffmpeg with).

Comment: Installing things with `curl` is very likely to end up causing a pain in the ass or breaking something in the future, and won't let you update automatically. I recommend using the answer from Stephen Hsu instead.

Answer (score 207):

For Ubuntu/Debian OS,

`apt-get install -y pkg-config`

For Redhat/Yum OS,

`yum install -y pkgconfig`

For Archlinux OS,

`pacman -S pkgconf`

For MacOS,

`brew install pkg-config`

Comment: Please note that the question was asked about osx.

Comment: Google still works with browsers on ubuntu though, and it landed me here. And a package-manager beats running arbitrary code `curl`ed over an insecure connection like the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: +1 to @AliSeyedi : The question was about OSX. I'm pretty sure that most Linux guys know how to install a package. It was not that obvious on a Mac.

Comment: When I performed the command on my Ubuntu, it required root privileges, i.e.- `sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config` (thought it is worth to mention it).

Answer (score 59):

for me, (OSX) the problem was solved doing this:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Comment: visit https://brew.sh if you don't have brew

Answer (score 25):

if you have this error :

```
configure: error: Either a previously installed pkg-config or "glib-2.0 >= 2.16" could not be found. Please set GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS to the correct values or pass --with-internal-glib to configure to use the bundled copy.
```

Instead of do this command :

```
$ ./configure && make install
```

Do that :

```
./configure --with-internal-glib && make install
```

Comment: Hi i have this error instead when i make install "symbol not found for architecture x86_64"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940264/unable-to-make-pkg-config
https://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.29.2.tar.gz version 0.29.2 has fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try

- which pkg-config
- if it is empty then fire

  1. brew install pkg-config
  2. **OR :** ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

**MacOS users**

Unfortunately, pkg-config does not come with OS X by default. Here are some notes on how to compile from source. It assumes that you have Xcode installed.

1. Download and extract

> ```
> curl -O http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.28.tar.gz
> tar xfz pkg-config-0.28.tar.gz
> ```

2. Configure and Install

> ```
> cd pkg-config-0.28
> setenv CC /usr/bin/cc (for tcsh)
> export CC=/usr/bin/cc (for bash)
> ```

2a) If you have super-user powers

> ```
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local CC=$CC --with-internal-glib
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

2b) if not

> ```
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/someplace/in/my/path CC=$CC --with-internal-glib
> make
> make install
> ```

Source: https://opensource.ncsa.illinois.edu/confluence/display/DESDM/Installing+pkg-config+from+source+for+OSX